# Mule ESB - moving mule application logs to different location

Tags: mule

I am planning to move mule application logs which are generated in `${MULE_HOME}/logs` folder to `D:\logs`.

I tried changing the configuration element in `${MULE_HOME}/conf/wrapper.conf` file as follows.

```
 wrapper.logfile=%MULE_BASE%/logs/%MULE_APP%.log
```

But its only copying single log file that is `mule.log`.

Is there any way we can move all the logs to a defined location?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inclue your log4j.xml  or log4j.properties code in the question that will help to find the exact solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` file defined for your application. Change path in that